# How can I add an image from my computer behind an already set image with Fabric.JS?

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I have an image with a frame that is transparent inside. It is set as the background of my canvas with CSS. I'm able to add images to my canvas but would like to be able to add only one image at a time to behind the transparent portion of the frame. How might I accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

```js
var id = document.getElementById('rectangle') && rectangle ||
  document.getElementById('anotherCanvas') && anotherCanvas;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id);

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (f) {
        var data = f.target.result;
        fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
            var oImg = img.set({
                width: 125,
                height: 170
            })
            canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
            var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'png',
                quality: 1
            });
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

#rectangle {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/0Mt6ho1.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="rectangle" width="637" height="412"></canvas>
```

[image: An image with the inside of the frame transparent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add to your fabricjs image object left top properties:

```
var oImg = img.set({
                width: 125,
                height: 170,
                left: 430,
                top: 65
            })
```

To make uploaded image behind you shouldn't use background image. You should insert regular image without controls. Something like this:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://i.imgur.com/0Mt6ho1.png', function (img) {
            var oImg = img.set({
                scaleX: 0.2,
                scaleY: 0.2,
                selectable: false
            })
            canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
           });
```

Then when you will upload image, you will need to make it selected, move behind, and deselected:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
            var oImg = img.set({
                width: 125,
                height: 170,
                left: 430,
                top: 65
            })
            canvas.add(oImg);
            canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
            var image = canvas.getActiveObject();
            image.moveTo(-1);
            canvas.discardActiveObject();
            canvas.renderAll(); 
        });
```

If you will select object with mouse it will automatically move your object to the top, but when you will deselect - it will move back again.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keuv590p/)

Comment: This places it in the right location however not behind the frame

Comment: If I'm going to use this to set the image instead of background, how can I assign different images to display on different canvases with JS? For example, right now I'm using CSS to control different canvas backgrounds.

Comment: You will need to add separately image to each canvas like code above.

Comment: Okay, so I can declare two canvases with something like `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('oval'); ` and `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('rectangle');`

Comment: You can, but you will loose reference to the first canvas. Declare 2 different variables for 2 different canvases. Please create new topic if you want to ask something.